# Steam installed but doesn't launch

Tags: software-installation, graphic-drivers, steam

So I have steam installed via a .deb package using Gdebi.

The steam icon is available and asked for my password when I run it but then nothing happens.

This is what happens if i type steam in terminal:

```
$ steam
Running Steam on elementary 0.4 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Here are my system specs:

Intel® Core™ i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz × 8

Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tobago PRO [Radeon R7 360 / R9 360 OEM] (rev 81)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The discussion in http://askubuntu.com/questions/771032/steam-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/772288 might help

Answer (score 1):

Open that package again with gdebi and remove it.
You have steam on the official repositories so just open Appcenter, search for Steam and install it.

Another method is to use the command line:

```
sudo apt install steam
```

---

Next time you want to install a .deb package, please, use this command instead of gdebi.

```
sudo apt install -f /your/folder/package.deb
```

This will check if the package is avaliable on the official repos and install it from there instead of using a deb file. It will also solve unmet dependencies.

Comment: Thank you removing the package with gdebi and installing with sudo apt install steam seemed to work the icon even changed it says updating steam now if I have any problems I will post a comment thank you both. One note if you click install in the app center at the moment after inputting the password it doesn't actually install Steam.

Answer (score 0):

First try:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
```